# Get neto area of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying for a while to find the neto area of element.
When I say "neto area" I mean - the actual visible area that we see on the screen.

for instance, you can see in news websites an image and text/headline on that picture, the text is covering part of the picture. In that case I would like to have the image area without the text area.

I have tried many methods such as recursion which is counting area of all elements - without succeed.

Is there any simple way to get that information?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Give an live example.

Comment: Where did you pick up the term "neto" for this?

Comment: Find the height of your image which is `x`. Find the height of your overlaid text which is `y`. `x - y = z`. `z` is the height of your 'neto area'. do the same with width.

Comment: @JustinWood - the problem is that I don't know all the elements that are covering this element, to be specific I don't want to find all covered. I just need the seen area..

Comment: I think that would need at least a javascript plugin. Counting only the parent container will maybe be correct in some cases, but what if nested elements are positioned visibly, but absolutely/ relatively outside the parent? You would need to determine offsets of each element, and if their position is not static, make more complex calculations, and also disregard the `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` elements

Comment: What unit do you want? px? cm?

Comment: @DoronCohen When you say "neto" do you mean net?

Comment: I think "Neto" should be "Netto": "Netto is Danish/Norwegian/Swedish/Dutch/German for "net" (the antonym of gross)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netto Gross is all, net only the visible part

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. "Neto" means the visible area.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width/height/area in px

**Pure JavaScript**

```
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
var width = el.offsetWidth;
var height = el.offsetHeight;
var area = width  * height;
```

**jQuery**

```
var el = $('#myElement');
var width = el.outerWidth();
var height = el.outerHeight();
var area = width * height;
```